# Autoextender is not working properly in asp.net on the search time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have one auto extender I want result should come with both

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> Get_challan(string prefixText)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BMS"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd12 = new SqlCommand("select distinct(product_accessories),delivery_cann from hardware where delivery_cann like @Name+'%' and **suppl_type=3**", con);
            cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
            SqlDataAdapter da12 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd12);
            DataTable dt12 = new DataTable();
            da12.Fill(dt12);
            List<string> CountryNames12 = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt12.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CountryNames12.Add(dt12.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            }
            return CountryNames12;
        }
```

In above code `suppl_type=3` this not working plz help me

Comment: do you get an error (if so which) or why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're sql is wrong, try this. The like with wildcard you can solve in the parameters.addwithvalue

```
SqlCommand cmd12 = new SqlCommand("select distinct product_accessories,delivery_cann from hardware where delivery_cann like @Name and suppl_type=3", con);
cmd12.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + prefixText + "%");
```